# How to upload multiple files from Vuejs and Vuex to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vuex

Im a using Vuetifyjs, and im trying to create a message system with attachments.

i use the Vuex async await for state management and sending http request.
however im sending json format request not multipart/form-data, would it be possible?

```
 //html input

<input type="file" multiple ref="attachments" @change="fileOnChange" />
```

```
data() {
   return {
      form: new Form({
          receiver: "",
          subject: "",
          content: "",
          attachments: []
      })
  }
}
```

```
//method

fileOnChange() {
      let files = this.$refs.attachments.files;

      if (!files.length) {
        return false;
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        this.form.attachments.push(files[i]);
      }

    },

sendMessage() {
   this.addMessage(this.form)
}
```

and when the action is triggered this is the Vuex code

```
async addMessage({ commit }, message) {
        const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
        const response = await axios.post("api/message", message, config);
    },
```

what is the best approach on this to store the files in the LARAVEL storage and save it in the database?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to go like this? FormData is needed to properly serialize the file contents, incase you can't use FormData you might try base64 encoding the file and then push it to `attachments[]` but I cannot guarantee that this is a good approach

Comment: you mean to say im going to use FileReader right?

Comment: What happen here is im creating SPA, vuejs is the frontend and vuex store for state management. I use Laravel as the backend. its kinda hard for me. So i guess, the best way to do this is to serialize form.

Comment: This is the most common setup

Comment: yeah i agree now, i tried passing base64 files, from javascript to php its kinda hard decoding base64. I tried but its corrupted. i have studied mime_type and I now realize. Its the best way to. serialize form to send post request with file attachment. thank you